# Update data on the view without page refreashing - Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, autoload

I want to load data frequently after 60 seconds without page refreshing. The line of code is

```
<div id="callmeauto">@include('custome.myquestionodds')</div>
```

The code in "myquestionodds.blade.php" in where the data is fetching. It is working fine. But I want to call this blade php file frequently and show in "callmeauto" div. I tried some codes from here there. But not working. As example below. I am sure I am in the wrong direction.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#callmeauto').load('/custome/myquestionodds');
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to use frontend framework to fetch data from endpoint in JSON format.

For example you can try to use [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) framework.
It in simple case your problem will be solved like that.

```
Vue({
    el: '#callmeauto',
    data: {
        contentToRender: "",
    },
    created() {
        this.loadContent();
        setInterval(this.loadContent, 60000)
    },
    methods: {
        loadContent(){
            axios.get('/custome/myquestionodds').then((response)=>{
                this.contentToRender = response.data;
            })
        }
    }
});
```

In your template you just use template syntax:

```
<div id="callmeauto">{{ contentToRender }}</div>
```

To use vue.js you will need to install it. Also [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library for making ajax calls.
The eases way via CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js></script>
```

Comment: "contentToRender " is undefined

Comment: @MdNurulAfsarPervez I don't know how your endpoint is destined.
Try to console.log(response);

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval` with 60 seconds

```js
function loaddata(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('custome/myquestionodds') }}",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#callmeauto').html(data);
        }     
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval(loaddata, 60000);
});
```

Comment: It is not replacing the old data or inner HTML content in "callmeauto" div.

Comment: Route for the view that I want to load

Route::get('/custome/myquestionodds', function() {
    return View::make('custome.myquestionodds');
});

Comment: so you need to call ajax to get updated data every 60 seconds

Comment: Again I tried this. The error I can extract from inspection: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () app.js:4 GET www.example.com/custome/myquestionodds 500 send @ app.js:4

Comment: check the error in inspect element + network + error see what error are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
app.js:4 GET https://example.com/custome/myquestionodds 500
send           @    app.js:4
ajax           @    app.js:4
loaddata       @    (index):1366
setInterval (async)     
(anonymous)    @    (index):1376
j              @    app.js:2
k              @    app.js:2
setTimeout (async)      
(anonymous)    @    app.js:2
i              @    app.js:2
fireWith       @    app.js:2
fire           @    app.js:2
i              @    app.js:2
fireWith       @    app.js:2
ready          @    app.js:2
S              @    app.js:3
```